# $("#i23").val(Number($("#f112").val())); how to i23 is a inputbox id result display intger not in decimal of float in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to convert `#i23` result into intger and not in decimal from float value in javascript.

```
$("#i23").val(Number($("#f112").val()));
```

Comment: If you want to convert a float into an integer you can use `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil`, `Math.round`.

Answer (score 0):

To convert in integer use `parseInt` instead `Number`

```js
$("#i23").val(parseInt($("#f112").val()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="f112" value="12.4125">
<input type="text" id="i23" value="">
```